# Decomposition of vector space by intersections

Tags: linear-algebra

> If a vector space has two deompositions $V = V_1 \oplus V_2 = W_1 \oplus W_2$, then is it  true that
> $V = \oplus_{i,j=1,2} V_i \cap W_j$

Of course, I guess so. But the following example is not so. Probably I have misunderstand but I cannot found it. Please let me know where is wrong.

Let $V$ be a three dimensional vector space and denote its basis by $e_1, e_2,e_3$.

Take another basis $f_1,f_2,f_3$ constructed from  $e_1, e_2,e_3$ as follows.
$$\begin{align*}
f_1 &= e_1 +e_2,\\
f_2 &= e_3,\\
f_3 &= e_2 +e_3.
\end{align*}$$

This transformation matrix has non-zero determinant.

Consider two decompositions of V, namely,

$V= (e_1,e_2) \oplus (e_3)=: V_1 \oplus V_2,$

$V= (f_1,f_2) \oplus (f_3)=: W_1 \oplus W_2.$

From  the following  calculations

$V_1 \cap W_1 =  (f_1),$

$V_1 \cap W_2 = 0,$

$V_2 \cap W_1 =  (e_3),$

$V_2 \cap W_2 = 0,$

I cannot deduce $V = \oplus_{i,j=1,2} V_i \cap W_j$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed your desired formula does **not** hold. Consider for example the two bases $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ and $\{(1,0),(1,1)\}$ of $K^2$, where $K$ denotes some field. Then
$$\begin{align*}
K\cdot (1,0) \cap K\cdot (1,0) &= K \cdot (1,0)\\
K\cdot (1,0) \cap K\cdot (1,1) &= \{0\}\\
K \cdot (0,1) \cap K \cdot (1,0) &= \{0\}\\
K \cdot (0,1) \cap K \cdot (1,1) &= \{0\}
\end{align*}$$
cannot possibly sum up to form $K^2$...

This proves in particular, that any vector space of dimension $\geq 2$ admits two such decompositions, which cannot be refined to make your formula hold.